# How to inject Utility classes with Guice in Play 2.5.4

Tags: java, playframework, dependency-injection, guice

I'm trying to load sample data into my database with play 2.5.4
Originally I'm following the tutorial on https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/JavaGuide1

But since it's written for Play 2.2 I'm try my best to adapt it and avoid the deprecated stuff.

Now, I'm still a little lost on the DI stuff.

What I have so far:

application.conf

```
play.modules.enabled += "GuiceConfiguration"
```

GuiceConfiguration.java

```
public class GuiceConfiguration extends AbstractModule{
    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        bind(OnStartupService.class).asEagerSingleton();
    }
}
```

OnStartupService.java

```
@Singleton
public class OnStartupService {

    @Inject
    private OnStartupService(Environment environment) {
        if (environment.isDev()) {
            if (Issue.find.findRowCount() == 0) {
                System.out.println("Okay");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Above code works fine!

The following not:

```
@Singleton
public class OnStartupService {

    @Inject
    private OnStartupService(Environment environment) {
        if (environment.isDev()) {
            if (Issue.find.findRowCount() == 0) {
                Ebean.saveAll((Collection<?>) Yaml.load("test-data.yml"));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Edit: fails with the following exception

```
play.api.UnexpectedException: Unexpected exception[CreationException: Unable to create injector, see the following errors:

1) Error injecting constructor, java.lang.RuntimeException: There is no started application
  at OnStartupService.<init>(OnStartupService.java:1)
  at GuiceConfiguration.configure(GuiceConfiguration.java:9) (via modules: com.google.inject.util.Modules$OverrideModule -> GuiceConfiguration)
  while locating OnStartupService
```

So I guess I should somehow inject Ebean and Yaml. But I'm only using static methods from those classes.
Can someone help me understand how to do this and why.

Comment: please do not edit your question and put answers in the question, especially when there is an accepted answer that is different! This is **not** a forum. Questions are for *Questions*, Answers are for *Answers* and Comments are for anything that is **not** a question or answer. Please take the answer and put it as a proper answer.

Comment: Okay understood. Would it be a good idea to change the subject, now that I understand what really the problem was?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the [code](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/2.5.x/framework/src/play-java/src/main/java/play/libs/Yaml.java) of `Yaml.java`, we can see that it uses the static `Play.current()` at line 20. That's why you get the error since there is no application started.

Furthermore, `Yaml` will be deprecated in 2.6 so I advise you to follow the [migration guide](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/737731bdf2f3a4bff8b6d94ce0852347ac49745f/documentation/manual/releases/release26/migration26/Migration26.md#removed-yaml-api). It explains you how to solve your problem :

1. Add dependency to `snakeyaml`
2. Create your own `Yaml` class
3. Inject `Application` inside it

**EDIT**

Then inject your `Yaml` class, do not use the static way :

```
@Singleton
public class OnStartupService {

    @Inject
    private OnStartupService(Environment environment, Yaml yaml) {
        if (environment.isDev()) {
            if (Issue.find.findRowCount() == 0) {
                Ebean.saveAll((Collection<?>) yaml.load("test-data.yml"));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok thanks. But the example in the link is wrong. They are trying to access an instance variable (environment) from a static context.

Comment: Exactly ! Looks like there is a mistake.

Comment: Ok thanks again. I try that later. I meant in the migration guide you linked. They had an example for a Yaml.class

Comment: Works exactly as you described.